# Unity - How to destroy my player by collision?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, destroy, gameobject

Hiho i simply try to destroy my object when it touches the redcube :) 
I used the code here https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html , but it wont work. Some ideas?

[image: pla]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playerdeath : MonoBehaviour
{

         void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
         {
             foreach (ContactPoint contact in collision.contacts)
             {
                 Debug.DrawRay(contact.point, contact.normal, Color.white);
                 Debug.Log("collision detected");
             }
             if(collision.relativeVelocity.magnitude > 2)
             {

                 Destroy(gameObject);
             }
         }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried giving tag to the redCube. And then use it in `OnCollisionEnter`?

Comment: it works but just with ontriggerenter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
 {
    if(other.gameObject.tag=="deathcube")
     Destroy(gameObject);  
 }
```

this worked fine :) but I have heard that its more performance heavy then OnCollisionEnter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:-

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playerdeath : MonoBehaviour
{

         void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
         {
             foreach (ContactPoint contact in collision.contacts)
             {
                 Debug.DrawRay(contact.point, contact.normal, Color.white);
                 Debug.Log("collision detected");
             }
             if(collision.relativeVelocity.magnitude > 2)
             {

                 Destroy(gameObject);
             }

             if(collision.gameObject.tag=="deathcube")
             {
               Destroy(gameObject); 
             } 
         }
}
```

**Note**: Add The Tag in Unity which I give in Screenshot.

[image]

Comment: no errors anymore but the gameobject still remains. Debug.Log("collision detected"); detects the collision